# Initialize a list (or array) of a variable length

Tags: vba

I know that we could declare a list of a fixed length in VBA by, eg, `Dim result as Variant` followed by `ReDim result(1 to 10)`. But I have difficulty in declaring a list of a variable length in VBA.

For instance, given a list `arr`, I would like to create another list `result` that removes all the empty and 0. I have written a code as follows:

```
Dim result As Variant
For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    If arr(i) <> "" And arr(i) <> 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve result(1 To UBound(result, 1) + 1)
        result(UBound(result, 1)) = arr(i)
    End If
Next i
```

This code does not run, because the length of `result` is not well initialised; and `ReDim Preserve result(1 To UBound(result, 1) + 1)` raises an error in the very beginning.

Does anyone know how to fix this code?

PS: If `ReDim` inside a loop causes a bad performance, could anyone suggest a better way to restructure the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining your code it looks like you are filtering arr to get result where result excludes values that are not "" or 0.  If this is the case then arrays are the wrong approach.  You should consider using a Collection, ArrayList or Scripting.Dictionary, preferably one of the latter two.

You can use ArrayLists in VBA if you add a reference to msCorlib.

You can use Scripting.Dictionary if you create a late bound object 'CreateObj("Scripting.DIctionary") or add a reference to the microsoft scripting runtime for 'new Scripting.DIctionary'.

The reason I would  recommend ArrayList or Scripting.Dictionary over Collection is that both of these objects can return arrays of the items they hold, which can be very convenient if you are working with Excel.

The Arraylist version of you code would look like

```
Dim myAL as ArrayList
Set MyAL = New ArrayList

Dim myItem as variant
For each myItem in arr

    If myItem<>"" and myItem<>0 then myAl.add myitem

Next

'If you need an array then
dim myResult as variant
myResult = myAl.toarray
```

The scripting dictionary version looks similar but requires a key for each item.  In you case an autokey generated by using mySD.count would be fine.

```vb
Dim mySD as Scripting.Dictionary
Set MySL = New Scripting.Dictionary

Dim myItem as variant
For each myItem in arr

    If myItem<>"" and myItem<>0 then mySD.add mySD.count,myitem

Next

'If you need an array then
dim myResult as variant
myresult = mySD.Items
```

FInally, if you know in advance that arr is composed entirely of string values, you could look at the VBA Filter function for onedimensional string arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the largest possible size of the array (in this case, It would be `UBound(arr, 1)` assuming that `LBound(arr, 1)` is 1) outside of the loop first then resize it again at the end of the loop:

```
Dim result As Variant
ReDim result(1 to Ubound(arr, 1)) As Variant
Dim resultCount As Long

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
   If arr(i) <> "" And arr(i) <> 0 Then
      resultCount = resultCount + 1
      result(resultCount) = arr(i)
   End if
Next i

ReDim Preserve result(1 to resultCount) As Variant
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you find the first value and then do
result = Array(arr(I))?

I just checked in the immediate pannel `?UBound(Array())` gives -1, so

```vb
Dim result As Variant
result = Array()
For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    If arr(i) <> "" And arr(i) <> 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve result(0 To UBound(result, 1) + 1)
        result(UBound(result, 1)) = arr(i)
    End If
Next i
```

should work with a 0-based "result" array or

```vb
Dim result As Variant
ReDim result(1 To 1)
For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    If arr(i) <> "" And arr(i) <> 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve result(1 To UBound(result, 1) + 1)
        result(UBound(result, 1)) = arr(i)
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239836/discussion-between-pchemguy-and-softtimur).